# Cancel Parallel.ForEach or use async await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel.foreach, async-await

I have this event:

```
private void  TextBoxSearchText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    searchText();
}
```

and I want to cancel this parallel method and start a new one when textbox text changes and also want my textbox be responsive to my new text typing, which is lock until results come to listbox.

```
List<TextList> oSelected;
private void searchText()
{
string strSearchText = TextBoxSearchText.Text;
    oSelected = new List<TextList>();            
    Parallel.ForEach(oTextList, item  =>
    {
        Match myMatch = Regex.Match(item.EnglishText.ToString(), "\\b" + strSearchText.ToString().ToLower() + @"\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!myMatch.Success)
        {
            return;
        }

        oSelected.Add(new TextList
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            EnglishText = item.EnglishText
        });
    });

    ListBoxAllTexts.ItemsSource = oSelected;
}
```

Is it possible to use async and awiat to accomplish the job?
Which one is better for searching a text in almost 1 million line of text?
I read alot about async and await but I couldn't understand how to use it in my work.
Thank you

Comment: I updated my question with adding string strSearchText to know how to implement it into searchText() method to get new text from textbox. Why couldn't I just create new string in my method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your work is CPU-bound, you should use parallel code to do the actual search. However, you can wrap the parallel work in an `async`/`await` mindset by using `Task.Run`:

```
private async void TextBoxSearchText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ListBoxAllTexts.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(() => searchText(TextBoxSearchText.Text));
}
```

This will keep your UI responsive.

To do cancellation, [use a `CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx). On a side note, you can't update a `List<T>` from a parallel loop like you're currently trying to do because `List<T>` is not threadsafe. In this scenario, I recommend you use PLINQ instead:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
private async void TextBoxSearchText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (_cts != null)
    _cts.Cancel();
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var strSearchText = TextBoxSearchText.Text;
  ListBoxAllTexts.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(
      () => searchText(strSearchText, _cts.Token));
}

private List<TextList> searchText(string strSearchText, CancellationToken token)
{
  try
  {
    return oTextList.AsParallel().WithCancellation(token)
        .Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(item.EnglishText.ToString(), "\\b" + strSearchText.ToLower() + @"\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        .Select(item => new TextList
        {
          Id = item.Id,
          EnglishText = item.EnglishText
        })
        .ToList();
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Also, consider throttling the user input by only starting the search after a delay. [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) is the best way to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I made some changes in question please check.

Comment: Updated to add `string strSearchText` as a method parameter.

Comment: Adding method parameter faces this error:  Player.MainWindow.searchText(string, System.Threading.CancellationToken)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: @MajidPoureftekhari: Fixed. You might want to consider getting a book on C#.

Comment: ERROR:An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

on TextBox text changed event